# Angular print a simple text in html

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this json

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "activityDays": 2,
    "coreBankingBranch": "master",
    "csrBranch": "master",
    "adminBranch": "master",
    "clientBranch": null,
    "creationDate": null,
    "serverName": "ATP",
    "cloneTag": null,
    "csrIsCompleted": false,
    "adminIsCompleted": false,
    "clientIsCompleted": false,
    "completed": false
  }
]
```

That I get from:

Component

```
 this.docker.getContainers().subscribe(containers => {
  console.log(containers);
});
```

Service

```
 getEnvironments() {
return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/environments", this.options);
}
```

And I try to print using

```
<tr *ngFor="let environment of environments">
      <td>{{ environment.name }}</td>
    </tr>
```

but I get

> ```
> EnvironmentComponent.html:79 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only
> ```
>
> supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: where is your environments array located?

you need to do something like this to start with:
`
getEnviroments() {
  this.enviroments = this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/environments", this.options);
}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998092/angular-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-obje/43998189

Comment: @user9793665 is your environments is an array type? E.G. `[{name:'name 1'}, {name:'name 2'}]`

Comment: @user9793665 Just bind environments array to the subscribes result.  `this.environments = containers`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not bind `environments` with the response. Also have to  initiate the `environments` in the component

```
this.docker.getContainers().subscribe(containers => {
  this.environments = containers  // assuming container is the shared response 
});
```

Comment: what type is this.environments? I don't want to create a class in the frontend and backend.. Can it be Object[] ??

Comment: If you are unsure just make it as `any` type. Also you can skip the `type`, just declare as empty array like `environments =[]`