# Angular6 error: the data which I am getting from api is in the string format,below is the response image

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

[image]hi want to show the data from my api to my frontend (Angular 6), but this error comes up: I am using HttpClient method from angular 6 I am new to angular

Angular6 error: the data which I am getting from api is in the string format, I need to convert it to object, below is the response image

this is model.ts

```
export class Incident {
public Title: string;
public status: string;
constructor(Title: string, status: string) {
this.status = status;
this.Title= Title;
}
}
```

this is component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Incident } from '../../shared/incidents.model';
import { DataStorageService } from '../../shared/data-storage.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-active-incident',
templateUrl: './active-incident.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./active-incident.component.css']
})
export class ActiveIncidentComponent implements OnInit {

incidents: Incident[];

constructor(private router: Router, private dataStorageService: DataStorageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataStorageService.getIncidents()
  .subscribe(
    (data: Incident[]) => this.incidents = data,
    (err: any) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('All done getting incidents')
  );
}
```

this is service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Incident } from './incidents.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataStorageService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getIncidents(): Observable<Incident[]> {
console.log('Getting all incidents from server');
return this.http.get<Incident[]> 
('api/url');
}
}
```

my json

```
{
"Events": ["{'title': 'some title', 'Incident_Status': 'status'}",
"{'title': 'some title', 'Incident_Status': 'status'}"]
}
```

html view

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let incident of incidents">
 <div class="card-header">
 <span class="badge badge-danger"></span>{{incident.Title}}
 <span class="badge badge-danger"></span>{{incident.Incident_Status}}
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: try *ngFor="let incident of incidents.Events" The incidents is not ar array is an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: 'Cannot find a differ supporting object '\[object Object\]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998092/angular-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-obje)

Comment: I am using latest angular 6 httpClient, and it has a separate way off getting data

Comment: Can I use json.prase() to convert string to object?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to iterate an object instead of an array. This happens because the list of events are inside the `Events` key, but you aren't accessing it to extract the list of events. Instead you are using the root of the response object.

Corrected code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataStorageService.getIncidents()
  .subscribe(
    (data: Incident[]) => this.incidents = data.Events, // <--
    (err: any) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('All done getting incidents')
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. I followed your above input as well. I am using *ngFor="let incident of incidents. incidents would already have array because i am using data.Events as you suggested However {{incidents}} this is giving me correct array of values, but when i try {{incident.Title}} this gives me empty instead of the value

Comment: It's lowercase `title`, did you try it with that?

Comment: yeah I tried with lowercase as well, infact value coming from api  is Title itself.

Comment: I got to know the error but i am not getting how to solve, its like the data which I am getting from api is in the string format, I do not know how to convert it now to object below is the example

Events: [,…]
0: "{'IE_Incident_Start_Time': '', 'IE_Start_time': '8/14/2018 10:50', 'Title': 'Intermittent Issues on CSP Login Page', 'IE_Start_By': '', 'Domain': 'IT', 'Impact': 'Users (Monitoring & External) will now be able to login to the CSP Login page without any issues.'}"

Comment: Added response image above

Comment: Can I use json.prase() to convert string to object?