# Angular2 won't load json file. Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent

Tags: json, angular, parameters

I am trying to load a json file into my Angular app, but can't find the culprit. It keeps telling me it can't resolve all parameters of my component.

(loading the data directly from the component worked, so it has to do with the code I added most recently for loading data from a json file)

My module:

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AppComponent } from './component.app';

@Injectable() 
export class Service {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getData(){
    return this.http.get('./assets/data/data.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
  }
}


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        Service
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

My component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './assets/partials/component-app.html',
    styleUrls: ['./assets/css/component-app.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

    tests: any;

    constructor(private service : Service){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getData()
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.tests = data;
        })
    }
```

The error:

```
(index):18 Error: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:14404:21)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:14301:28)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:14074:30)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:14167:51)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:14161:51)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:16803:49)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:16741:39)
        at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:16732:23)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:6954:29)
```

data.json, I need to loop through test_cases and Test_steps:

```
{
"test_run_id":  "A233-CA92-3293-B9AA",
"app_name": "Chewy.com",
"time_stamp": "2018-01-20T12:00:00Z",
"test_cases": [
    {
        "test_name": "View dog bone",
        "status": true,
        "test_steps": [
            {
                "step_name": "Click Dog Category",
                "screenshot": "file1.png",
                "launch_times": [
                    100,
                    134,
                    123
                ],
```

HTML:

```
<section class="tested-app" *ngFor = "let item of tests">
    <h2>----<span> {{ item.app_name }} </span>----</h2>
    <p id="time"> Time: <span> {{item.time_stamp}} </span> </p>
    <section class="flexWrap">
        <div class="module" *ngFor="let subItem of item.test_cases">
            <h3> {{ subItem.test_name }} </h3>
            <p class="status"> {{subItem.status}} </p>
            <div class="step" *ngFor = "let testStep of subItem.test_steps">
                <h4>{{testStep.step_name}}</h4>
                <img src="../assets/images/{{testStep.screenshot}}">
```

Comment: where have you imported service in your component? You need to import Service in your AppComponent

Comment: Do you have access to the JSON file to make changes in that? I know the better way of doing it

Comment: @theLearner how do I do that?

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar yes I do have access to the json file.

Comment: @calluna see my answer as text is long for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import your service in app.component.ts

```
import { Service} from '...';
```

you also need implement OnInit

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
```

In your `getData` function, you have typo:

```
return this._http.get('./assets/data/data.json')
```

And the most important is you need put your service out of `app.module.ts` Why? Because it will create a circular dependency: 
app.module.ts -> app.component.ts -> app.module.ts

Create a new service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable() 
export class Service {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getData(){
    return this._http.get('./assets/data/data.json')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Import it in app.module

```
import { Service } from './service';
```

Comment: Looks like that worked! Though now I have an error about my data..?

Error in assets/partials/component-app.html:1:28 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: @calluna can you post your template and json file. You could check this to fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660306/angular2-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object

Comment: So I have added:
 .map(res => res.json().test_cases)
 .map(res => res.json().test_steps)

And no more error!!!
However, no data either -_-    :-P

I posted the first part of my json and posted my HTML template as well in the original post

Comment: When I was loading the data from the component it was working well, so there must be something in the service code...From what I can see it is recognizing there is data as it is looping through it and outputting the HTML, just no data

Comment: Ok, I got the other stuff figured out too... Your answer helped me get through this issue for sure! With that I was able to continue my search for the rest.. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the first line:

`import { Component } from '@angular/core';`,

you need to add a line

`import { Service } from X`

where X is the path of the file which defines Service. I guess in your case you are defining Service in `app.module`, so try

`import { Service } from ./app.module.ts`

(if app.module.ts is in same directory, otherwise include path to that directory)

Comment: I added the error to my original post (too long for a comment)

Comment: The same error comes if you define the service in a new file?

Comment: @calluna did putting service in new file resolve the issue?

Comment: If I do that I get even more errors... I shouldn't have to put it in another file..? I got my code from this example where they also don't use a separate file: http://plnkr.co/edit/clJcJ1Wbk6MVaNoBU8ZV?p=preview

Sorry I am new to Angular; so when I put it in an another file, I am not sure what I miss but I introduce more errors.

Comment: Don't say sorry. Let's try to solve your problem and everyone might get a chance to learn something new

Comment: I think I am making headway, I split up my service from my components. And I think it is picking up my data because now I am getting this error:
(see my original post, I added the first part of my data)

Error in assets/partials/component-app.html:1:28 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: ok, I have added 
.map(res => res.json().test_cases);
.map(res => res.json().test_steps);

and I don't have any errors anymore!! But no data showing up either
I posted the first part of my data and HTML

Comment: When I was loading the data from the component it was working well, so there must be something in the service code...From what I can see it is recognizing there is data as it is looping through it and outputting the HTML, just no data