# Does not display a separate post

Tags: angular

I need your help. I take data from the JSON placeholder resource, display posts and try to make each post have a posts-details page and open this page instead of all posts. As a dynamic page for each post. However, I'm getting errors in the posts-`details.component.ts` file that look like this:

`TS2322: Type 'IPost[]' is not assignable to type 'IPost'.`,
`TS2739: Type 'IPost[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IPost': id, title, body`

Please help with this problem. I will be very grateful

posts-details.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {IPost} from "../models/posts";
import {PostService} from "../services/post.service";

@Component({
selector: 'app-post-details',
templateUrl: './post-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./post-details.component.css']
})

export class PostDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

fullPost: IPost

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private postService: PostService) {
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.postService.getDifferentPost(params['id']).subscribe(value => this.fullPost = value)
})
}

ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

post.service.ts

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {IPost} from "../models/posts";

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PostService {

private url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

getPosts(): Observable<IPost[]> {
return this.httpClient.get<IPost[]>(this.url)
}

getDifferentPost(id: number): Observable<IPost[]> {
return this.httpClient.get<IPost[]>(this.url + '/' + id);
}

}
```

my routes in `app,module.ts` file

```
let routes: Routes = [
{path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, children: [{path: ':id', component: UserDetailsComponent}]},
{path: 'posts', component: PostsComponent},
{path: 'posts/:id', component: PostDetailsComponent},
]
```

post.ts

```
export interface IPost {
id: number,
title: string,
body: string
}
```

posts-details.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="fullPost">
{{fullPost.title}}
{{fullPost.body}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting IPost array from the service, but you are adjusting the service response into singular IPost element. You should handle as this:

```
fullPost: IPost[]

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private postService: PostService) {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
     this.postService.getDifferentPost(params['id']).subscribe(value => this.fullPost = value)
  })
}
```

and also in your html file :

```
<div *ngFor="let post of fullPost">
{{post.title}}
{{post.body}}
</div>
```

Comment: @Faith Ersoy, If I do this, I will get an error in the post-details.component.html file: 
`Unresolved variable title, body`

Comment: Hello, I just updated my answer due to the changes of your .html file. You should not use ngIf for arrays, use ngFor instead.

Comment: Happy to hear this!

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you again(( After it, in the console i have an following error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`. My application works, but in component `post_details.compoent.html`, i got it. Sorry((

Comment: It means that your backend response is not in full array form. You should first look for the data you're getting from your backend (you can simply console.log the response). Someone overcome this issue by using JSON.parse(fullPost) or you can try <div>{{post | json}}</div>. If that was not helpful you should see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35660306/14693246

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to resolve this issue. Anyway, this is my github with this project:
https://github.com/Dmytrii9Cherniak/AngRoutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240479/discussion-between-frankenstar-and-fatih-ersoy).